# How to launch a hidden application on Android with sh command?

Tags: android, metasploit

In metasploit i already hide an application with hide_app_icon command. 
Im trying starting an application with these commands

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.metasploit.stage/.MainActivity
sleep 60
done
```

but its give an error like this

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.metasploit.stage/com.metasploit.stage.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

When app icon not hidden from launcher its okay.

Where is the problem?